# I am not able to store google map location info in variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Friends,
Now i am using google API for getting the Location Info.I am getting the location info but i am not able to store that neither in variable nor in a hidden field. Can any one help me to know where i am doing mistake.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  

   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;// = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address;        
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("<%=txtLatitude.ClientID %>").value, document.getElementById("<%=txtLongitude.ClientID %>").value);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 5,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(document.getElementById("<%=txtLatitude.ClientID %>").value, document.getElementById("<%=txtLongitude.ClientID %>").value),
            map: map,
            title: 'Click me'
        });
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ "latLng": latlng }, function(data, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                address = data[0].formatted_address;
                alert(address);
            }
        });           
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Location info:' + address + '<br/>LatLng:' + document.getElementById("<%=txtLatitude.ClientID %>").value + ',' + document.getElementById("<%=txtLongitude.ClientID %>").value            
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    window.onload = initialize;
</script>
```

Comment: To my understanding what ever you have stated as error isn't error. Your infowindow is showing the content as undefined. Am I right?

Comment: Yes,right. That is now a problem for me.

Comment: It is showing correct information in Alert, but when i am accessing that same inside InfoWindow it is showing "undefined".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error. You are initializing the infowindow with the content before assigning to the marker. Set the content in the event handler.

This is how your code should be-

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

               infowindow.setContent('Location info:' + address + '<br/>LatLng:' + document.getElementById("<%=txtLatitude.ClientID %>").value + ',' + document.getElementById("<%=txtLongitude.ClientID %>").value);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message (which should be in your question, not tucked away in the comments), implies that you don't have an element on your page with whatever ID `<%=hdnAddress.ClientID %>` equates to.  What is the value of `<%=hdnAddress.ClientID %>` and can you show us your HTML which should contain it?

Comment: I have tried it in variable also. it is showing same error."Location info:undefined"
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();           
            geocoder.geocode({ "latLng": latlng }, function(data, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {                   
                    address = data[0].formatted_address;
                }
            });           
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Location info:' + address 
            });

Comment: well because you only create address `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) ` there's a possibility it is undefined when you create your infowindow.  Initialise `address` as an empty string at the top of your function

Answer (score 0):

The first element of an array has index 0, not 1, so instead of `data[1].formatted_address;` you should use `data[0].formatted_address;`

Comment: data[1].formatted_address will also work. May not be the issue

Comment: Only if there is more than 1 result, which is not always the case.

Comment: I agree to it. Lets see if that helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
But i am sorry to say that it is not working it is showing the same error "Location info:undefined"

Comment: You never said you were getting "Location info:undefined" in your original post. **Please learn how to ask questions properly** instead of wasting other people's time.

Comment: @Marcelo thanks for you valuable comments. Its realy help me to resolve my issue.